# Again N Again Split the string with "#"

Tags: android

I want to split the String with the `#` symbol

'#Happy#sad#Angry#Tear and so on`

I don't know how many times user enters hashtags so how can I split that String?

I tried this:

```
    allhashtag= String.valueOf(edt_hashtag.getText());


              String tag1[] =allhashtag.split("#");
               String tag2= tag1[0];
```

Comment: What is the problem with the example code you show? Have you tried adding a zero second argument (for [this overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)), which is the default of what you're doing anyway? And please take some time to read (or refresh) about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try for loop for split String when we don't know how many characters in String 
Try this code:

```
String s = allhashtag;

if(s.toString().contains("#"))
 {

     String tags[]=s.toString().split("#");
      for (String tag : tags)
      {
        Log.e("tag",""+tag);
       }

 }
```

Comment: It's Work for me@Darshi Domadiya